# Pulling specific data from a repeating table

Tags: excel, vba

[A test export showing 2 sample points as they come from the software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Fpf.png)I have data from over 100 sample points exported in to excel. I want to pull specific pieces of information from these in to a summary table.
Each sample point exports as discrete table and the tables repeat every 11 rows. Ie if b4 contains an analyte (A) value from sample 1 then b15 contains the (A) value for sample 2
I want to be able to pull all of the A values, as well as other values out. In total 6 analytes found across rows 3-7 columns B-D and then repeated 11 cells down to create a table (data from 11 cells down copied in to the second row of the new table and so on) [This is an example from a previous report where I manually pulled all of the data and created a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzeiS.png)

I have successfully created a macro to pull across this data from the first sample in to a second sheet and i believe  i need a repeat next function but i cannot work out how

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D3").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2")
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2")
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D2")
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B6").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E2")
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B7").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F2")
End Sub
```

This is the macro i have at the moment

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you are attempting to do. Can you provide sample of your sheets and what the output sheet should look like?

Comment: I have added in images to try and clear this up

Answer (score 0):

Based on the requirements, the following should do what you need:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim sourcesheet As Worksheet
    Dim destsheet As Worksheet
    Dim repeat_x_times As Long, loopcounter As Long
    Dim onelocation As Long, spread As Long
    Dim locations As Variant
    Dim locationlist As String

    '---------------------------------------
    '     edit these as you see fit
    '---------------------------------------
    Set sourcesheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set destsheet = Sheets("Sheet2")
    locationlist = "D3,B4,B5,B6,B7"
    spread = 11
    repeat_x_times = 6
    '---------------------------------------

    locations = Split(locationlist, ",")

    With sourcesheet

        For loopcounter = 1 To repeat_x_times
            For onelocation = 0 To UBound(locations)
                .Range(locations(onelocation)).offset((loopcounter - 1) * spread, 0).Copy destsheet.Cells(loopcounter, 2 + onelocation)
                'or if you don't need formatting, just values (much quicker):
                'destsheet.Cells(loopcounter, 2 + onelocation).Value = .Range(locations(onelocation)).offset((loopcounter - 1) * spread, 0).Value
            Next
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

I've made this easily configurable to your needs, just edit the variables:

`locationlist` is the list of cells you want to pick up, in the order you want them output on sheet2.

`spread` is the offset between repeats.

`repeat_x_times` is the number of rows you want output.

I've used the copy statement similarly to your existing code, but if you don't want to copy formatting etc. you can just use a value switch. I've commented out the code but if you want to use it, un-comment it and comment out the `copy` line.